# video to frames in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing

I have a code to extract frames from a video.The code is given below

```
addpath('E:\project\coding\wrk_ongoing\Images');
obj = mmreader('ace.mp4');
vid = read(obj);
frames = obj.NumberOfFrames; %Read the Total number of frames and displyed in     command window 
  ST='.jpg';

cd frames
for x = 1:5         %  extracting the 5 frames from video
  Sx=num2str(x);
  Strc=strcat(Sx,ST);
  Vid=vid(:,:,:,x);
  imwrite(Vid,Strc);
end
cd ..
```

This code works only for some videos.I tested for different videos with .mp4 extension.Some of them works well. But input videos shows error as

> > ??? Error using ==> vid2frame at 6
> >     Initialization failed. (No combination of intermediate filters could be found to make the
> >     connection.)

how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is due to your video file itself.  From the looks of it, MATLAB has a problem reading that file probably because the file is badly encoded or the video was encoded with a codec that is not supported by MATLAB or does not exist on your computer..  See this question for a similar problem: [no combination of intermediate filters could be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23963098/no-combination-of-intermediate-filters-could-be-found)

This has nothing to do with MATLAB, but the error was what you encountered and the answer was to essentially re-encode the video file in a format that is compatible with your operating system and MATLAB.

---

Good luck!