# No combination of intermediate filters could be found to make the connection

Tags: vb.net-2010

My problem is that when I am running this application on my laptop  it is working fine. but when I install on client computer it is giving following error:

> No combination of intermediate filters could be found to make the
>   connection

```
Private Sub btnPatient_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPatient.Click
    Try

        If txtPatientName.Text.Trim = "" Then
            MsgBox("First enter patient name.")
            txtPatientName.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If btnPatient.Text = "Camera" Then
            btnDocument.Enabled = False
            ccPatient.BringToFront()
            Dim _CameraChoice As CameraChoice = New CameraChoice()
            _CameraChoice.UpdateDeviceList()
            If (_CameraChoice.Devices.Count > 0) Then
                Dim camera_moniker = _CameraChoice.Devices(0).Mon
                ccPatient.SetCamera(camera_moniker, Nothing)
            End If
            btnPatient.Text = "Capture"
        Else
            SaveImage()

            btnPatient.Text = "Camera"
            btnDocument.Enabled = True
            btnSave.Focus()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        GlobalFunctionClass.ExceptionMessage(ex.Message, "btnCamera_Click", Me.Text)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [no combination of intermediate filters could be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23963098/no-combination-of-intermediate-filters-could-be-found)

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23963098/no-combination-of-intermediate-filters-could-be-found